# linux bash, print line contaning string in a column

Tags: linux, bash

let's say my file /etc/passwd contains

```
ntp:x:38:40::/etc/ntp:/sbin/nologin
avahi:x:70:70:Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack:/var/run/avahi-daemon:/sbin/nologin
haldaemon:x:38:68:HAL daemon:/:/sbin/nologin
pulse:x:497:495:PulseAudio System Daemon:/var/run/pulse:/sbin/nologin
gdm:x:42:38::/var/lib/gdm:/sbin/nologin
sshd:x:388:74:Privilege-separated SSH:/var/empty/sshd:/sbin/nologin
tcpdump:x:38:72::/:/sbin/nologin
```

what i'm trying to do is print the line containing a "38" in the third column, something which will print this:

> ntp:x:38:40::/etc/ntp:/sbin/nologin haldaemon:x:38:68:HAL
>   daemon:/:/sbin/nologin gdm:x:42:38::/var/lib/gdm:/sbin/nologin
>   tcpdump:x:38:72::/:/sbin/nologin

I tried something like

```
cat "/etc/passwd" | cut -d ":" -f3 | grep "38"
```

but it only show the "38" not the entire line

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could  use grep

```
grep ^.*:.*:38:  /etc/passwd
```

Improved version after tripleee's comment:

```
egrep ^[^:]*:[^:]*:38: /etc/passwd
```

Comment: This will find any occurrences in the fourth column, too. I grant you that the OP's example output exhibits the same problem (-: ... and you can fix it by changing `.*` to `[^:]*`.

Answer (score 3):

you may test this:

```
awk -F: '$3~/38/' /etc/passwd
```

note that 3rd column with 338 or 838 will be printed as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can use wk:

```
awk -F: '$3==38{print}' file
```

In general, I would suggest you avoid parsing `/etc/passwd` directly. Instead you can use `getent passwd`to read the passwd database.

Comment: +1 The first answer posted is still the best, four additional answers later.

Comment: No need for the `{print}`, it does that by default.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
cat /etc/passwd  | egrep "^[[:alnum:]]*:[[:alnum:]]*:38:.*"
```

Using the alphanumeric character class.

Comment: Fredrik Pihl is right about UUoC. Sorry, guys. ;-) Just do $ egrep "^[[:alnum:]]*:[[:alnum:]]*:38:.*" /etc/passwd

Answer (score 1):

In pure bash (awk is the way to go though!):

```
$ while read line; do array=(${line//:/ }); [ ${array[2]} -eq 38 ] && echo $line; done < input
ntp:x:38:40::/etc/ntp:/sbin/nologin
haldaemon:x:38:68:HAL daemon:/:/sbin/nologin
```

Comment: Or `IFS=: while read a b c d e f g; do case $c in 38 ) echo $a:$b:$c:$d:$e:$f:$g;; done </etc/passwd`

Answer (score 0):

only `sed` was remaining :)

`sed -n '/^[^:]*:[^:]:*38:/p' /etc/passwd`